# How to refresh JQuery mobile table after a row is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, html-table, dynamically-generated

I am adding rows to a JQ Mobile table based on a JSON string that I am getting from the server.

The first time I go to the page after a refresh, none of the styling is added, however everything works fine everytime after that.

Is there a way to refresh/initialize a table as you can for listviews?

The code below is where I am adding the rows:

```
$.each(result, function() {
    var imgString;

    if(result[i]["status"] == 'Y') {
        imgString = '<img src= images/checkMark.png height=\"40\" width=\"40\" align=\"middle\">';
    } else {
        imgString = '';
    }

    $('#pickupTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td class=\"tableRow10\">' +  imgString + 
      '<td class=\"tableRow80\"><a><button class=\"selectPickup\" pickupCode = \"'+ 
      result[i]["id"] + '\"> '+ result[i]["address"] +'</button></a></td></tr>');
    i++;
});

$('#pickupTable > tfoot:last').append('<tr><td colspan="5">Total Pick Ups: ' 
  +result.length + '</td></tr>');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried your example in Chrome and got styles right away.  Perhaps there is an issue with the mobile device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you use .trigger('create'); and refresh the page, jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

> **Enhancing new markup**
>  The page plugin dispatches a pagecreate event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. As long
>   as a widget plugin script is referenced, it will automatically enhance
>   any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.
>
> However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via
>   Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to
>   handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within
>   the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page
>   div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin
>   (listview button, select, etc.).
>
> For example, if a block of HTML markup (say a login form) was loaded
>   in through Ajax, trigger the create event to automatically transform
>   all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this case) into the
>   enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

Answer (score 7):

You *should* be able to just use:
`$("#myTable").table("refresh");`

But it hasn't been implemented for version 1.3.0 of jquery mobile.

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5570

Sounds like you have to either add the rows before the page is initialized, or don't set the table's attribute *data-role="table"* until after the rows have been added.
    `$("#myTable").table();`

In the implementation I am working on, I allow users to add rows. Luckily for me the site is designed to be viewed with larger mobile devices so I can wait for 1.3.1

Comment: good point of adding `data-role="table"` at a later stage. Problem still is, how to refresh, when for example paging through rows.