# refresh section tag on submit using jquery in a jqueryMobile HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I am using a jquerymobile template from Dreamweaver6.0 and building a mobile app interface. On home screen, I have four buttons - say, **View, Create, Update, Delete**.
When I click **Create**, it opens a new screen (each screen that opens from these four buttons are defined as "sections" within the same index.html page).

In **create** "**section**", there are few form fields and a **submit** button. When I click on **submit**, my form values are being submitted to the database (I am using AJAX to do this). But the problem here is my page won't refresh when I click on Submit.

What I am looking for is, the "**create section**" should refresh once I click on **submit** and a drop down list existing in the "**view**" section of the same index.html page also should refresh (this section has newly entered details as drop-down elements, dynamically update from database.)

the HTML code:

```
<section data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
  <header data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>CRUD Experiment</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content"> <a href="#view">
    <input value="View" type="button" data-role="button" data-icon="info">
    </a> <a href="#create">
    <input value="New" type="submit" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">
    </a> <a href="#updatePage">
    <input value="Update" type="submit" data-role="button" data-icon="refresh">
    </a> <a href="#deletePage">
    <input value="Delete" type="submit" data-role="button" data-icon="minus">
    </a> </div>    

  <footer data-role="footer" class="ui-footer-fixed">
    <h5>Cnonymn</h5>
  </footer>
</section>

<section data-role="page" id="view" data-theme="b">
  <header data-role="header"> <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left  ui-btn-hover-c"> Back </a>
    <h1>CRUD Experiment</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content">
    <form>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="names">Select Employee</label>
         <select name='names' id='names' size='1' onchange="getDetails(this)">
         <option>Select</option>
        </select>               
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input value="Show All" data-role="button" onClick = "getAllDetails()" type="button">
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="emp_tb1" align="center" data-theme="b">Here are the details </div>
  </div>
  <footer data-role="footer" class="ui-footer-fixed">
    <h4>Cnonymn</h4>
  </footer>
</section>

<section data-role="page" id="create" data-theme="b">
  <header data-role="header"> <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left  ui-btn-hover-c" onClick=""> Back </a>
    <h1>CRUD Experiment</h1>
  </header>
  <div data-role="content">
    <form method="post" id="myForm">
      <label for="emp_name">Name</label>
      <input name="empName" id="emp_name" value="" type="text" data-theme="a">
      <label for="emp_dob">Date</label>
      <input name="empDOB" id="emp_dob" value=""  data-theme="a">
      <label for="emp_gender">Gender</label>
      <select name="empGender" id="emp_gender" data-role="slider" data-theme="a" data-inline="true" style="display:none;">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <textarea name="empAddr" id="e_address" value="" type="text" data-theme="a"></textarea>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="image">Add Image</label>
      <input name="image" id="image" value="" type="file" data-theme="a">
      <br>
      <br>
      <label for="multimedia">Add Multimedia</label>
      <input name="multimedia" id="multimedia" value="" type="file" data-theme="a">      
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="insert" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="someElement"></div>
  <footer data-role="footer" class="ui-footer-fixed">
    <h4>Cnonymn</h4>
  </footer>
</section>
```

What and where should I write the refresh functionality? This refresh should both "refresh the form screen" and "update dropdown list"

Comment: any help is appreciated. kindly look in to the issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead refreshing the whole page(it would take longer time), you can reset(refresh) the forms.

Add IDs to your forms, and after ajax submit successfully, you can reset these forms.

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/SjbMd/5/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn_submit').on('vclick', function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        $(".ui-loader").show(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: 'data',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Form successfully submitted!');
                $("#viewForm")[0].reset();
                $("#myForm")[0].reset();
                $(".ui-loader").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi @yeyene - thank you for your response. I have exactly the same function written. But added the ".reset()" methods to the function. Only the current form fields are getting reset. The form which has the drop-down is not getting reset. I am not sure why. Is it because it's in a different section tag?

Comment: check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/SjbMd/6/ , i didnt call the ajax submit and move the scripts outside ajax call, it also reset select form, you select anything first, then, fill the new form and submit. Then go back and check the select form.

Comment: ok. I think the problem here is - my drop-down works based on a script. It dynamically populates values from the database. and this is only working when I do a whole page refresh.
The code I am using for populating my dropdown is as follows - 

function loadlist(selobj,url,nameattr)
{
    $(selobj).empty();
    $.getJSON(url,function(data)
    {
        $.each(data,function(i,obj)
        {  
        $(selobj).append('<option value="'+obj['id']+'">'+obj['name']+'</option>');
        });
    });
}

Comment: Just the form reset() (where my dynamically being populated drop-down is there) is not working here. reset() is only clearing off the field values or it's just setting back the form fields to their previous state.
what I am looking for is, the drop-down should "reload" - are there any methods that can reload just a drop-down?
Or can you please suggest me a different way to populate my drop-down, and which works with "reset()"?

Comment: is there any reason you want to reload drop-down list, i mean reloading will load the same data again, right?

Comment: no, reloading the drop-down should add-up the newly entered row from the database. Now am manually refreshing the page to see the new entry within the drop-down.

Comment: so, you can call again the drop-down list populate function again, after ajax success. loadlist(); it should refresh your drop-down, coz it is only one html file with different page sections.

Comment: logically, that's what I understood and did try the same.. but some how... after the ajax call and the loadlist(), it's not showing up :( 
By the way, my data is coming from a PHP file. Would that be an issue?

Comment: or, there is an onclick reload page function, try this one? onclick="location.reload(true)"

Comment: hmm that's a good work-around for now i hope. But the screen jumps when reloaded :(

Comment: @yeyene... any idea on how to toggle the flip switch (am using it for Male/Female choosing option in a form) based on the database value?

Comment: of course, check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/hRfwB/1/ ... try to change variable sex value from Male to Female and see effect.

Comment: you are just amazing. I think I need to think more deeper. It looks simple after you gave me the demo on jsfiddle. I tried many other things to do this. (for e.g. I tried to use my loadlist function which did not work - logically it won't :( )

Comment: now, everything is working fine right, glad it works for you.

Comment: @yeyene.. hope you are doing good.. can we refresh a table after an AJAX call? like how we do for a listview? 
$('data-role=listview').refresh('listview')

Comment: That will do, please see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334633/how-to-refresh-jquery-table-after-a-row-is-added-dynamically

Comment: @yeyene... thanks for your reply! I've already tried that but the style applies only for my first row.. :( all other rows (out of my 10 rows) look simple HTML. Also, am not able to get this as responsive. It looks good for a computer screen and a mobile screen. It fails for a tablet screen resolution