# Dynamically Set data-filter-reveal Attribute in Filtering Table in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am adding data-filter-reveal attribute dynamically using javascript based on logic. Can you please help me how to refresh the table / enhance this widget when dynamically attribute is set / changed.

I have tried the below but no luck.

```
$('.tableselector').table('refresh'); 
$('.tableselector').trigger('create');
```

Please refer the Snippet in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5e8euthp/2/)

Comment: sorry, i thought its listview

Comment: pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334633/how-to-refresh-jquery-mobile-table-after-a-row-is-added-dynamically

Comment: Nope.. No luck.. tried applying the refresh, trigger.. also as said in the link above.. moved the data-role after the table data is populated.. seems refresh, create is only for the data dynamically set.. not for the attribute dynamically set...

Comment: can u create the new table with the existing data and remove old one,

Comment: assign whole innerhtml to the new table, dont know wether it will work

Comment: thanks for answering.. yeah tried clone the old table data to new table data.. it had issues filtering the data..

Comment: Below code made the difference.. when dynamically set the table attribute, it looks we need to trigger the pagecreate and content create events...  `$('#PageContent Selector').trigger('create');`
 `$('#Page Selector').trigger('pagecreate');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the filterable widget options:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-filterReveal

```
$('#ToggleRevealTrue').click(function () {
    $( "#movie-table" ).filterable( "option", "filterReveal", true );
});

$('#ToggleRevealFalse').click(function () {
    $( "#movie-table" ).filterable( "option", "filterReveal", false );
});
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5e8euthp/3/)**

Comment: thanks.. pagecreate event is the one which needs to be called when attribute is dynamically set..